# How to refuse work task solicitation

Tags: work-life-balance

I have been a programmer for a long time now and have gainned experience and knowledge over years of studies. Working in the field of computer also made me a source of knowledge for basic tasks (simple problems resolution, OS configuration ...)

My issue is that I'm often solicited by family, friends or acquaintances to do tasks that are trivial for me, but sometime hard or impossible for them. When it is family I normally just do it and it doesn't bother me much as it stay really simple and they are kind about it.

But with others, I'm sometime being ask to do tasks that are part of their job but for which they are lacking technical skills. For example last time, a friend had a problem with his enterprise main website and solving the issue took us about half an hour where I had to dive into his code. I often give a hand because I like to help and to face challenge. But it's really annoy me as I feel like some of them are just using me.

How can I draw a line and tell them that their task is kind of what I do for living and should not be something they can ask me to do simply for help ? It feel like the situation with graphic designers, where they are asking "hey could you do a logo for me, it won't get you too long". And I don't really know how to deal with it.

Note: I don't want to ask them for a compensation or anything, I just don't want them to ask me for these kind of help.

Comment: What is the business relationship you have with the friend for whom you fixed the enterprise web site? Do you work for the same company, or are you fixing something for his company because your friend/his company has decided not to hire anyone qualified to fix websites.

Comment: I had no link to his business, the task was a bug fix that happen to took more time that planned. It is a close friend and he was stuck on it for a while.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is not just that one guy? It sounds like whenever he can't do his job, he's going to ask you to bail him out.  In your question you give friends and family as an example but then also say you don't mind helping with them.

Comment: My experience is to not even help them the first time as it is rarely appreciated and does not stop.  They can get mad because they did not know how to make it work. Even worse something breaks and they expect it is your fault and problem.  Send them to StackOverflow.   Now trade out is different thing.  I have a buddy I do computer work for free but he lets me use his shop for free.

Comment: No, I unfortunately have solicitation at least once a month. And it come from various person. My recent example was poorly chosen as it was one of the worth case.
I'm not bothered when it come to family or very close friend (that will surely find a way to thank me). But I don't know how to deal with peoples asking for help because I have the knowledge to their problems and as you said, won't appreciated the help to it's true value.

Comment: You are no different than a Dr or lawyer that does not want to work for free or even take on side jobs for cash.  Just politely tell them no.  Avoid talking about work in the first place.   I had a guy say to me once I should "let" you fix my laptop and I said after that are you going to let me clean your bathroom.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want compensation? You could ask for *anything*.. and if they're desperate enough they may even take you up on it! Goodbye afternoon of lawn-work, hello 30 minutes of computer help. Anyone who is trying to "use" you won't ask for that too often ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Workplace. OP's friends are not at his workplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of strategies to use for this.  When it is someone outside of my closest circle I will often ask "What's in it for me?" in a joking way.  Often people will offer me things other than cash that I appreciate, like help with moving, fresh baking, babysitting, etc.  If you would just rather the requests stop then either politely say no or if you are uncomfortable doing that make them your bottom priority.  People are less likely to ask again if you only commit to help them weeks in the future.

Comment: Will try to apply your advices in the future, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> But with others, I'm sometime being ask to do tasks that are part of
>   their job but for which they are lacking technical skills.

Ask what have they done to solve the problem so far. Lot of times, people can troubleshoot their own problem and learn in the process.

If your friend attempted to find a solution and was unsuccessful, then offer your time to help

Answer (score 0):

I may do *discounted* work for friends, or do simple things for free, or arrange a trade -- but that's a gift I'm giving them, and the discount is off full cost at consulting rates. Nobody is ever entitled to demand a gift or dictate its size. If they aren't satisfied with what I offer, they are welcome to go elsewhere.

"I'm sorry, I really don't have the time." End of discussion unless they offer to make it worth your time.

"No" is a perfectly legitimate word.

Comment: "No." isn't just a legitimate word.  It is a full sentence.